# window.scroll and scrollTo not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, filemaker, scrollto

I have a simple javascript that works perfectly on Mac and PC platforms, but stubbornly refuse to scroll on any iOS device.

```
function scrollWin(ctx) {window.scroll((XSobject Map_zoom_x) - Xwindow/2, (YSobject * Map_zoom_y) - Ywindow/2);}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this function to work on iOS devices? The rest of the scripting plots a map and this final step should scroll the window to the location on the map, so it is pretty essential. However, any iOS device ignores it and shows the map at the origin.

I have tried embedding it in a setTimeout but that doesn't help either. window.scroll does the same thing.

Many thanks for any pointers for this. Anatole

Comment: Nobody any ideas on this issue yet?

I have tried delaying the process at various points. I have used setTimeout to delay the scrollto function, tried window.focus, window.setTimeout, window.AddEventListener, window.focus, window.observe - but all to no effect. Whilst I am a novice at this, the script works perfectly in a normal browser, but just ignores the final step that scrolls the image to the desired location.

Any other ideas out there?

Comment: Are you missing a '*' between 'XSobject' and 'Map_zoom_x' ? Just doesn't match the pattern in the second half…

Comment: My apologies Paul - but well spotted. Indeed you are right it should be: 
window.scrollTo((XSobject * Map_zoom_x) - Xwindow/2, (YSobject * Map_zoom_y) - Ywindow/2);
So thanks, but that is not the problem. Believe that it may be to do with the way that iOS handles the scrolling on a touch screen and the code ignores the JavaScript scroll commands. I was just hoping that there might still be a way to get the window to scroll from the coding.